# emberjs - RESTful resource handling

Tags: ajax, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to load sample data from a REST API [source](http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/) that return XML inside my emberjs app but I am facing two problems:

1. The model name is always in plural, so instead of /sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/ the code always generate /sqlrest/CUSTOMERS/3/
2. I know that DS.RESTAdaptor expects by default JSON format so I was wondering is there any way I can still get XML format and may be convert to JSON?

Thanks

Code I am using is as follows (This code I found in one of SO replies and altered to match the URL I am trying to access):

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        namespace: "sqlrest",
        url: "http://www.thomas-bayer.com",
        plurals: {
            'customer': 'customer'
        },
        ajax: function (url, type, hash) {
            hash.url = url;
            hash.type = type;
            hash.dataType = 'jsonp';
            hash.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
            hash.context = this;

            if (hash.data && type !== 'GET') {
                hash.data = JSON.stringify(hash.data);
            }

            jQuery.ajax(hash);
        },
    })
});
```

and in route:

```
App.CustomersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //return App.Customer.find();
    //New
    return App.Customer.find(18);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at ember-restless which allows XML consumption:

https://github.com/endlessinc/ember-restless

For pluralization, take a look in here:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L476

The only thing is, obviously if you're going to use ember-restless, you'll need to find the relative point in there that you need to override in a similar way (if it's possible to customize endpoints).